# take indexes between repeated values

Tags: php, arrays

how can I get everything from a repeated index and the other in an array? see:

```
$Produtos = Array(  'Guitarra' , // repeats
                       'Bateria' ,  // repeats
                       'Piano' ,  
                       'Baixo' , 
                       'Guitarra' ,  // repeats
                       'Violão' , 
                       'Caixas de Som' ,
                       'Bateria' , // repeats
                       'Sanfona' );
```

Reviewed are the indices that are repeated, as I do to get what's between them?
I wish to return:`

```
Array
(

    [0] => Array( 
              [0] => Piano
              [1] => Baixo
    [1] => Array( 
              [0] => Violão
              [1] => Caixas de Som
    [2] => Array( 
              [0] => Sanfona
    ) )
```

Comment: can u be more clear about what do u want /?

Comment: how more clear ? i explained all i need , yes, i store them.

Comment: O que você pretende ? retirar os itens repetidos ?

Comment: Não. Veja o exemplo de retorno que eu dei, espero que retorne o que está entre os itens repetidos.

Comment: This is an extremely odd way to structure an array. What exactly do you want (ie: why do you want the return to be the way it is?)

Comment: Zuka burro, agradeceu pra todo o mundo e esqueceu do Portuga ? deve ser complexo né ?

Answer (score 1):

It can be solved like this:

```
<?php
<?php

$Produtos = Array(  'Guitarra' , // repeats
                       'Bateria' ,  // repeats
                       'Piano' ,
                       'Baixo' ,
                       'Guitarra' ,  // repeats
                       'Violão' ,
                       'Caixas de Som' ,
                       'Bateria' , // repeats
                       'Sanfona' );


$countedProducts = array_count_values($Produtos);

$c = 0;
foreach ($Produtos as $product)
{
    if ($countedProducts[$product] > 1)
    {
        if (count($novosProdutos))
        {
            $c++;
        }
    }else{
        $novosProdutos[$c][] = $product;
    }
}

print '<pre>';
var_dump($novosProdutos);
print '</pre>';

?>
```

Output:

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(5) "Piano"
    [1]=>
    string(5) "Baixo"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(7) "Violão"
    [1]=>
    string(13) "Caixas de Som"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(7) "Sanfona"
  }
}
```

I have understood in the meantime, what you really wanted to have as an result. I changed it now, and it work also with multiple repeations and starts always from zero.

Comment: see my return, I wish to create an index for every item that is among those that repeat themselves.

Comment: It is working now. I haven't understood the task at the first time and unfortunately I can't speak portugese.

Comment: Yup, it's working, even speaking Portuguese I didn't get it at first too, the user disappeared, without even saying "obrigado" :)

Comment: Yes indeed, that's really annoying.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

function array_between_duplicates($ary)
{
  // first, tally up all the values
  // we need to know how many times each value repeats
  $count = array_count_values($ary);

  // next, we want only the values that are not repeated.
  // This can be done by filtering the array for values
  // present 2+ times
  $between = array_filter($count, create_function('$a','return $a==1;'));

  // now that we have the unique values, swap the keys
  // and value locations using array_keys
  $swap = array_keys($between);

  // and then intersect the new array with the original
  // array so we can get back their original key values.
  $intersect = array_intersect($ary, $swap);
  var_dump($intersect);

  // now, in order to get the nested groups we will use
  // skipped keys as a sign that the in-between values
  // were repeats. So, iterate over the array and break
  // out these groups
  $result = array(); $group = array();
  foreach ($ary as $key => $value)
  {
    if (!array_key_exists($key, $intersect) && count($group) > 0)
    {
      $result[] = $group;
      $group = array();
    }

    if (array_search($value,$intersect) !== false)
      $group[] = $value;
  }
  if (count($group) > 0)
    $result[] = $group;

  // return the result
  return $result;
}

var_dump(array_between_duplicates($Produtos));
```

Results in:

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(5) "Piano"
    [1]=>
    string(5) "Baixo"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(7) "Violão"
    [1]=>
    string(13) "Caixas de Som"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(7) "Sanfona"
  }
}
```

**[DEMO](http://www.ideone.com/MQEZH)**

Comment: see my return, I wish to create an index for every item that is among those that repeat themselves.

Comment: Worked, Thanks, you see Jeff answer ? more generic.

Answer (score 0):

```
$finalProducts = array();
$currentKey = 0;
$wordCount = array_count_values($Produtos);
foreach($Produtos as $val) {
    if($wordCount[$val] > 1) {
        $currentKey++;
    }
    elseif(strlen($currentKey) > 0) {
        $finalProducts[$currentKey][] = $val;
    }
}
$finalProducts = array_values($finalProducts);
```